# How to create a WebKit browser plugin in C#?

Tags: c#, cross-platform, plugins, webkit

I want to create C# plugin for some 3d + Music editing stuff. I want to be able to run my files inside browsers pages (so to see HTML some Flash content and some content which is rant by my plugin) using something like HTML tag or some JavaScript. (So my plugin will be small, powerfull and i want it to run at least on Windows and Mac firefox and safary and Chrome)(If it'll be runing on Linux itll be grate)))

I'ma beginner so any helpfull info will be appriciated

Comment: Oh. Making browser plugins is a browser-specific task. You would need to ask browser developers for the appropriate documentation.

Comment: May I suggest that you begin with a smaller task if you're a pure beginner?

Comment: IE uses COM for plug-ins, so you can have a COM-callable wrapper for your C# code, but other browsers are C++-based and you'd need at least a C++ wrapper around your .NET code.
As @Sylvestre wrote, this is way too complex for a beginner. 
Write first a stand-alone music editing program (quite complex by itself), then write a 3D program (very complex, too). Then, in a couple of years, tackle the browser plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it using Silverlight .. think abt it .. :)

Comment: +1 uk80 - Silverlight is a great choice for a beginner. Also, what he's describing doesn't seem like it requires the complexity of a browser plugin, and Silverlight would be easier to deploy and update.